# Libreoffice converting HTML to PDF on command line produces empty page

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, headless

When I am using a html document ('*SimplePage.html*') with the following content

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <body>
    This is just a simple Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

Libreoffice (LibreOffice_5.1.2 on Windows 7) produces an pdf having the first page blank and then writing not the full text - instead only "**a simple Hello World**" is shown

I am using the following command line

```
soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf SimplePage.html
```

When I do the conversion not in headless mode (opening Libreoffice writer and the using "Export" the generated pdf is correct. Therefore I think it's not a problem of the used HTML.
Does anyone know the reason and a solution to this problem?

Comment: Where the text is shown? If it starts right at the left edge of the page then it might be that the start of the sentence is "off page", ie the start coordinate of the text is for some reason negative (when we consider the left edge as zero coordinate). Also you could look inside the pdf to see is the text actually there (easier if the content stream of the page is not filtered).

Comment: yes, the test is shown on the second page at the upper left corner. It does not look like the text is inside the file, because several pdf readers cannot find any parts of the string. I also tried to look inside via notepad++ without any success. The strange thing is that via the graphical interface of libre office the pdf is created correctly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try writhing this:

```
soffice.exe --headless --norestore --writer --convert-to pdf YOURFILE
```

it worked for me, the point was to add `--writer option`

Comment: To expand on this answer, by default Open/LibreOffice converts an HTML to PDF using the `writer_web_pdf_Export` filter. Using the `--writer` option or the `*writer.exe` binary changes the default to `writer_pdf_Export`, which seems to work better for many documents. Another option is to specify the exact filter you wish to use: `--convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export` along with any filter-specific options.

Answer (score 1):

i ran into this issue recently, even with writer_pdf_Export, and discovered that adding a Content-Security-Policy meta tag seemed to resolve it.  i used...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="sandbox">
```

and this seems to resolve the hello-world case above as well...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="sandbox">
      <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      This is just a simple Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

(checked using the current LibreOffice 7.0.4.2)